# 3 way ANOVA / Duncan test

Tags: anova, bonferroni

I am runnig 3 way ANOVA between: specie * organ * treatment in Sucrose acumulation.

There is interaction between organ*treatment, but no interaction between specie and organ or treatment.

1. Should I discard specie factor and continue in  a 2 way ANOVA (using organ and treament as factors)?
2. I doing a Duncan test before ANOVA to know in which groups sucrose acumulation means are similar. Should I use alfa-bonferroni correction (alfa/number of samples, in my case 0,05/12) before running Duncan test or should I just use alfa= 0,05?

Many thanks

Andres

Comment: Did your 3-way model include 2-way interaction effects? Or did you run a new test to identify the interaction between organ*treatment?

Comment: First, sorry I did not reply this months ago. Now that I am learning in stats I can answer you.

My model included a 2-way interaction effect, in which I just had interaction between organ and treatment factors.

Many thanks @indigochild